# $\frac{1}{2\pi} / \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2\pi}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\frac{\frac{1}{2\pi}}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2\pi}}}=\frac{\frac{1}{2\pi}}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\pi}$$

Is the above correct? If so how do I get the below:

[image]

It appears

$$\frac{\frac{1}{2\pi}}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2\pi}}}=\sqrt{\frac{2}{2\pi}}$$

Comment: $\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2\pi} = 2\sqrt{\pi}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first line is incorrect.

$$\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{2\pi}}{\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2\pi}}}=\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{2\pi}}{\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}}=\dfrac{\sqrt{\pi}}{{\pi}}$$

Comment: Oh ... what a silly mistake ...